# How to make pairs of two without recurring pairs from list

Tags: python, python-3.x, list

I'm trying to create a function where a list from range 1 to X is put into a list consisting of pairs of 2, then shuffle the pairs X-1 times, so that there are X-1 times a list of pairs i,j in 1,..,X where i,j are never the same.

The pair are players in a Prisoners dilemma game with a perfect stranger match. So I want each players has to play `X-1` games, i.e. play once against each of the other players.

The players are stored as `[1,2,3,...X]` in a list. And the pairs are are stored in a list of lists `[[1,2],[2,3],...]`.

So far, I was able to create the first round, and now I want to change the list of players so that the next round has different pairs. And I want to do this X-1 times, but (as I said) that there are should be no repeating pairs.

```
players = list(range(1, int(input()+1)))
rounds = list(range(1, len(players)))

for round in rounds:
    pairs = []
    for idx, i in enumerate(players):
        a = players[idx]
        b = players[idx-1]
        if b > len(players):
            continue
        else:
            pairs.append([b,a])

    for idx, x in enumerate(pairs):
        c = pairs[idx]
        d = pairs[idx-1]
        if c[0] == d[1]:
            pairs.remove(c)

    print(pairs)
```

So now I need to change something to then iterate over the for loop with the number of rounds...

I tried this in the loop:

```
players.append(players[1])
players.remove(players[1])
```

my output currently looks like this:

```
8 
[[1, 2], [3, 4], [5, 6], [7, 8]] 
[[1, 3], [4, 5], [6, 7], [8, 2]] 
[[1, 4], [5, 6], [7, 8], [2, 3]]
[[1, 5], [6, 7], [8, 2], [3, 4]]
[[1, 6], [7, 8], [2, 3], [4, 5]] 
[[1, 7], [8, 2], [3, 4], [5, 6]]
[[1, 8], [2, 3], [4, 5], [6, 7]]
```

Any ideas are much appreciated and thanks in advance..

Comment: some indents are missing.. the "rounds" for loop is the first loop and includes all others..

Comment: `import itertools` and then `pairs = list(itertools.combinations(players, 2))`

Comment: From the output shown, you just want to get rid of the repetitions?

Comment: I want to create the output new, with no repetitions, which is then all possible pairs ((1,2) and (2,1) are the same) playing one time.

Comment: @blogbeard unfortunately this does not quite do it, since the pairs for each round do have to be in one row, so that the output is a matrix which rounds and pairs, where every round plays every player. So no [[1,2],[1,3],[1,4]], in this case it has to be: [[1,2],[3,4],[5,6]] and the next round e.g. [[2,3],[4,5],[6,1]]